# Selenium phantomjs does not work for twitter.com

Tags: python, webdriver, phantomjs

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS('./phantomjs')
browser.get("https://twitter.com/")
print browser.title
```

print returns null
cant figure why browser.title returns u''

```
browser.get("https://google.com/")
print browser.title
```

but now it prints Google

so its bit frustrating why twitter.com not responding with Phatomjs in Selenium Web Browser

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior with PhantomJS 1.9.8, Selenium bindings 2.44.0 on windows 7.

Comment: at first you need to download phantomjs zip version and need to extract phantomjs.exe on your Python main folder (for example C:\Python27 ), only then you can bind phatomjs with selenium webdriver

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS 1.9.8 does the work for twitter.

New version available here: http://phantomjs.org/download.html

Previously I used the older version of the PhantomJS: 1.9.7.